# concede word usage

Tags: word-usage

I never seem to remember the meaning of word 'concede' even though I looked up in a dictionary about ten times. So I decided to make up 5 sentences so the word finally sticks to me. Can someone please tell me if my understanding/usage is correct?

> 1. I never thought she would concede her wrongdoings at the end. (Verb)
> 2. I did not know if she can be concessible. (Adjective)
> 3. The party acknowledged concededly. (Adv)
> 4. This time of the year, people are more generous and easily concede any special requests. (Grant)
> 5. There is no  choice but to be a country of conceder for PNG as it lacks man power and financial resources. (Noun)

Comment: #'s 2,3,5 sound wrong because of your derivations of 'concede'. I've never heard those before. Did your dictionaries allow those? A lot of derivations are just not mentioned in dictionaries, but in these cases they don't work. 1and 4 are perfectly fine.

Comment: @Mitch: I'm as surprised as you are. But they do exist according to wiktionary. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/concededly  http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/concessible

Comment: I used the http://www.thefreedictionary.com/concede and http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conceder.

Comment: The latter has additional forms of the word 'concede' where i found: concededly, adverb
conceder, noun
concessible, adjective

Comment: @Ananda ... and since the free dictionary did not give any clues as to their meanings, you took a wild guess and came out completely wrong. Voting to close for the reason of not enough research. There are actual definitions in other dictionaries on line.

Comment: Please refer to a good dictionary for various derived word forms (POS) related to *concede.* We may not always "make up" other POSs in an arithmetical way in the English language. (I suppose the OP is a non-native speaker of English.) Generally it is only *v.i.* or *v.t.* with *conceder* as a rare noun and *conceding* the gerund form. *Concessible* is literary. *Concession* is only etymologically related. *Conceded* and *concededly* are understably permissible derivations, though. HTH.

Comment: Apart from meaning, we need to familiarize ourselves with the **usage** of a word and its various derivations to correctly form sentences. Please refer to example sentences from GoogleBooks. Good Luck.

Comment: Yes I am not a native speaker, learning a lot from your comments. Thank you.

Comment: Alert to OP: Please show background research effort -- you are earning close votes! (not mine.)

Comment: By the way, the (very common) noun corresponding to the object of the verb 'to concede' is 'concession'. For the person who concedes, you really don't want to use 'conceder' but rather a phrase like 'the country that conceded'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are missing the spirit of making concessions, and worse you are close enough to general understanding of the word *'concede'* that many of your critics will purport that you are correct.

> **cede** - relinquish ownership [or control] of (some possession).
>   **concede** - resign, cease resistance; ‘to give up’ an argument, standoff, impasse, etc.; withdraw prior contention or opinion from conversation for the sake of moving on.

**Pleading 'No Contest' (*nolo contendere)* in court proceedings is a real-life example of conceding that adequately respects the many facets of the meaning behind the word '*concede*':** (these are not synonyms but rather ingredients necessary for 'concede' to apply)

- a dispute
- reluctance to change opinion or admit/feign agreement
- Unwillingness to endure a battle of incompatible opinions
- The value of a potential eventual victory is no longer greater than the expected value derived from officially maintaining a conflicting opinion.

Pleading 'No Contest' tells the court that you are aware of the charges and that you do not intend to fight the charges; you thus concede the case and your opponent wins by default. Similarly, conversations and arguments can hit standstills and impasses that prevent the conversation from continuing normally, or even amicably, until someone **concedes** and decides to give in, ***whether or not their opinion has been swayed whatsoever.***

"Fighting a losing battle" and "throwing good money after bad" are phrases that attempt to highlight the futility of an endeavor, its "rightness" or "wrongness" notwithstanding.

Some commentary on your examples:

> I never thought she would concede her XYZ at the end. (Verb)

XYZ in this case can be things like **belief, opinion**.
XYZ would be something that opponents would be attempting to show to be invalid.
XYZ in this case is notably **not** anything physical. (You can't concede your wallet or your glasses.)

> I did not know if she can be concessible. (Adjective)

Here, 'she' would have to stand for some idea that we endearingly refer to as feminine, like "Lady Liberty".

> The party acknowledged concededly. (Adv)

This sounds more like it is meant to describe that "the party reluctantly acknowledged their defeat."

> This time of the year, people are more generous and easily concede any special requests. (Grant)
>   Here, **'accommodate'** would be a far better choice than 'concede' for many reasons:
>   Here, ***'requests'*** *are* concessible.

All in all:

> When that would otherwise be in wait, pending you concede, you are seeking to continue an interaction, situation, or dialogue, even though you may or may o longer agree with the premises.

Answer (score 1):

I have never encountered the words *concessible* (Sentence 2), nor *concededly* (Sentence 3), nor, it seems, has Oxford Dictionaries Online.

In Sentence 5, though the word *conceder* exists, I am puzzled as to what a *country of conceder for PNG* (Papua New Guinea?) might be. It makes no sense to me.

Sentences 1 and 4 are fine.

**Later Edit.**

Having gone to higher authority - the OED - I've discovered it does have ***concessible***, meaning 'that which can be conceded', with the following examples:
,

> 1767   L. Sterne Life Tristram Shandy IX. xxiii. 82   It was built
>   upon one of the most concessible postulatum in nature.
>
> 1845   T. Carlyle in O. Cromwell Lett. & Speeches I. 452   Their
>   claim,..was just:..though full of intricacy; difficult to render clear
>   and concessible.

and ***concededly*** meaning 'admittedly'.

> 1882   N. York Tribune 22 Mar.   The present Executive Mansion..is
>   concededly not what it ought to be.

**Notwithstanding my discoveries of these somewhat archaic forms I am still having difficulty grasping the meaning of sentences 2 and 3.**

Comment: I'm as surprised as you are. But they do exist according to wiktionary. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/concededly http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/concessible

Comment: Concededly, these words exist; but the OP's suggested usages are completely wrong.

Comment: My sentence may have been incorrectly structured. What I wanted to say is PNG is a small, powerless country so it tends to compromise when dealing with other countries. I.e., definition below: 3. To make a concession:
compromise.
Idioms: give and take, go fifty-fifty, meet someone halfway.

Comment: WS2: Dictionaries, even the best like OED, do not always give all possible morphological derivations (prefixes and suffixes). So you can't take the absence of evidence as evidence of it not existing at all. It gives possibly a hint, but is not proof. Of course we agree on these particular words, they sound very 'made up'. However, I do like 'concessible', and will endeavor to engage in legal action just in order to be able to use it.

Comment: @Mitch Oh yes - the mighty OED had them - though with no examples since the 19th century. It was the puny little Oxford Dictionaries Online which didn't include them.

Comment: @Ananda Perhaps what your sentence was trying to say was: *There is no choice for a small and powerless country like PNG but to be a conceder in its relations with larger countries.*